# A generic error occurred in GDI+ / ASP.Net only when deployed on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, gdi+

We have this method in our code. It converts an image (png, gif etc.) to jpeg.

```
  public static byte[] ImageToJpeg(byte[] content, long quality)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] fileContent = null;
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream readMemoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(content))
            {
                using (System.Drawing.Bitmap image = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(readMemoryStream, true))
                {
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder encoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo jpgCodecInfo = GetEncoder(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1);
                    System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter encoderParameter = new System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(encoder, quality);
                    encoderParameters.Param[0] = encoderParameter;

                    using (System.IO.MemoryStream writeMemoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                    {
                        image.Save(writeMemoryStream, jpgCodecInfo, encoderParameters);
                        fileContent = writeMemoryStream.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            return fileContent;
        }
        catch (System.Exception exception)
        {
            System.InvalidCastException invalidCastException = new System.InvalidCastException("Invalid conversion", exception);
            throw invalidCastException;
        }
    }
```

It works fine for all images on our locale machines. When deployed on server we get an *"A generic error occurred in GDI+"* error for SOME (not all) images in this method.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] including one of the images which is failing.

Comment: [System.Drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.drawing?view=netframework-4.7.1#Remarks): "**Caution** Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions. For a supported alternative, see Windows Imaging Components."

Comment: @mjwills I know this would be helpful. Unfortunately, all the sample images I currently have contain confidential data. If I remove the sensitive data, the error suddenly does not occur anymore (because I changed the image).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That sounds not good. So the only option is to rewrite the code?